# How do I get the maximum length of the string in each column in an attribute table in QGIS?

Tags: pyqgis

I want to know for each column in a layer what the longest string is in that column

For the moment just a print out is fine

Answer (score 0):

Try this one

Where the column is a number it will convert to string so you can see the string equivalent length

```
directory = 'C:/Temp/'
fileName = 'TheFile.gpkg'

layer = QgsVectorLayer(directory + fileName,'Layer') 
field_names = [field.name() for field in layer.fields()]

for fieldName in field_names:
    list_of_values = layer.aggregate(QgsAggregateCalculator.ArrayAggregate, fieldName)[0]
    try:
        print('Maximum length of ' + fieldName + ' is ' + str(len(max(list_of_values, key=len))))
    except:
        print('Maximum length of ' + fieldName + ' is ' + str(len(max([str(x) for x in list_of_values], key=len))))
```